# Return value from onload method and assign to variable

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to return value from a onload method and assign to a variable in javascript? I have multiple values to be returned from method.  I don't want to print that in html (I know how to print) but I want it to assign to a variable.

```
<html>

<div id="screenCapture" onload="screenProperties()">Screen properties</div>

<p id="sW"> <p>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function screenProperties(){

    sW=screen.width;
    sH=screen.height;
    saW=screen.availWidth;
    saC=screen.colorDepth;
    pixelDepth=screen.pixelDepth;

return  "sw:"+sW+"sH:"+sH+"saW:"+saW+"saC:"+saC+"pixelDepth:"+pixelDepth;

}
alert(screenProperties());
</script>

</html>
```

is my method. Here, I want to assign the returned value to a variable in html side.

Comment: The person who down voted, do you have any solution for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion

```
var scP = {
 "sW":screen.width,
 "sH":screen.height,
 "saW":screen.availWidth,
 "saC":screen.colorDepth,
 "pixelDepth":screen.pixelDepth}
```

Now you can use

```
scP.sW
```

anywhere you need

for example:

```js
var scP = {
  "sW": screen.width             || "not available",
  "sH": screen.height            || "not available",
  "saW": screen.availWidth       || "not available",
  "saC": screen.colorDepth       || "not available",
  "pixelDepth": screen.pixelDepth|| "not available",
  "bla": screen.bla              || "not available"
}

window.onload = function() {
    // need window.onload to wait for sprops div to render
    document.getElementById("sprops").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(scP); // all
    document.getElementById("pd").innerHTML = scP.pixelDepth;
    document.getElementById("sw").innerHTML = scP.sW;
    document.getElementById("bla").innerHTML = scP.bla;
}
```

```html
<div id="sprops"></div><br/>
<div>
  sw: <span id="sw"></span>, 
  pd: <span id="pd"></span>
  bla: <span id="bla"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do we need to wait for `window.onload` to retireve valid `screen` object properties ?

Comment: No. But we need window.onload to wait for the HTML to render where we want to show it

Comment: I would go with the `DOMContentLoaded`. Anyways, your answer makes lot of sense now..

Comment: I have used window.onload since 1996, served me well :)

Comment: _I was just 6 by that time :P_  MDN describes it as [__It is an incredibly popular mistake__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: However 1) it is a mistake to use .load if you do not know what you are doing and 2) domcontentloaded is not supported by older browsers. In real life there are millions of IE8s

Comment: I knew something is coming my way ;) No hard feelings :P

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using onload event for div (doesn't work on all browsers), use the onload event of windows

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    screenProperties();
  });
  var sW,sH,saW,saC,pixelDepth;
  function screenProperties()
  {
    sW=screen.width;
    sH=screen.height;
    saW=screen.availWidth;
    saC=screen.colorDepth;
    pixelDepth=screen.pixelDepth;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: addEventListener also does not work in all browsers. `window.onload` does. Also you code could be written `document.addEventListener("load",screenProperties);`

Comment: No need to call the method from div like <div id="screenCapture" onload="screenProperties()">Screen properties</div>
 ??

Comment: @Sanjay yes no need to call it from div onload, since the event may not exist at all

Comment: Also no need to call from any onload since the properties are available when loading